# Why don't we get electrocuted from atmosphere while standing on ground?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, potential, everyday-life

I have been thinking about it for some time and I have found some explanations. However none of them were concrete enough. More specifically, I believe that there should be at least a little current between our bodies and the air but it sounds unsatisfactory as our bodies are capable of detecting very small currents.

Nevertheless, please provide some arguments for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Wikipedia article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_electricity

There is a weak conduction current of atmospheric ions moving in the atmospheric electric field, about 2 picoAmperes (2 x 10$^{-12}$A) per square metre, and the air is weakly conductive due to the presence of these atmospheric ions.

To put things into perspective, according to IEC 60479-1 (Effects of current on human beings and livestock-Part 1)
the thresholds for ventricular fibrillation electric shock are about 35-40 milliamperes AC (50/60Hz) and 120 milliamperes DC, or currents that are 10-11 orders of magnitude greater than the current associated with the atmospheric electric field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suppose that only counts as "weakly conductive" for geophysics purposes. For electronic engineering, air is an insulator :)

Comment: @user253751Yes of course. There are so many variables. For one thing conduction current in the atmosphere does not directly translate to current through the body and of course air is an excellent insulator (unless it breaks down). I am merely trying to show the many orders of magnitude between electric shock and atmospheric current (except, of course, lightning current).